# operators as variables name in java same like #define in c

Tags: java, c, operators

```
#define AND=&&;
public static final  String  AND = &&; //GIVES ERROR
```

i want to define the operators as normal variables names in my code same like we do in C language using #define, how do i do that in java ?

Comment: I wonder what abomination you did in the C code. And then I reconsider and do not want to know.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do that in Java.

Java does not have a preprocessor.

Comment: there should be some way

Comment: @saurabh kumar you can use c preprocessor with java

Comment: no problem ,simply i want to know if its possible or not by some other ways

Comment: Indeed, it's a fair question. I upvoted it ;-) But as it's not part of the language, I'd refrain from contrivances like using preprocessors from other languages.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Just opened your profile, it's showing your profile-pic corrupted... How did you get that done?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not come with a preprocessor, however there are some out there such as http://code.google.com/p/pre-processor-java/.  It is also possible to use C's preprocessor.  However in general it is frowned upon in Java, the creators of Java purposefully left it out of the language.